# button fade-in at bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button in my footer which fades in once the user reaches the bottom of the screen.

HTML - inside  tags

```
 <script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
    isShown = true;
    $('.footer-btn').fadeIn(500);
}
});
</script>
```

I want it to fade in 150 pixels before the user reaches the bottom, not the absolute bottom. Also I want it to fade out when the user scrolls back up. But I am unsure how to add to my code to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 150 from document height and write in else to fedout.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()-150){
    isShown = true;
    $('.footer-btn').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('.footer-btn').fadeOut(500);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 150)) {
        $(".btn").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $(".btn").fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/swaipa/3bhj95br/)

Comment: awesome, same answer as provided, almost the same time.

Comment: Well, I see that I use a > instead of ==. That is just to be on the safe side =)